# Matplotlib - selecting colors within qualitative color map

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting many scatter plots together, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 50

x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y, c='blue')

x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y, c='green')

x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y, c='goldenrod')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I am doing this for >10 scatter plots and I would like to choose colors from a qualitative colormap to get color balance & separation, e.g.:

[image]

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: E.g. to get the third color of `Pastel1`, use `c=plt.cm.Pastel1(2)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I find it pretty neat to use an iterator to be able to select the next color in the list:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

colors = iter([plt.cm.tab20(i) for i in range(20)])

N = 50

x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=[next(colors)])

x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=[next(colors)])

x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=[next(colors)])

plt.show()
```

[image]